# Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components, laravel-blade

app.js

```
var Users = {
    template: `
        <tr v-for="list in UsersData">
            <th>{{ list.idx }}</th>
            <td>{{ list.id }}</td>
        </tr>
    `,
    data: function () {
        return {
            UsersData //get data from query
        }
    }
}

var mainview = new Vue({
    el: "#mainview",
    components: {
        'users': Users
    },
    method: {}
})
```

layout.blade.php

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <aside>...</aside>
        <main id="mainview">
            @section('content')
            @show
        </mainview>
    </div>
</body>
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>IDX</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <users></users>
    </tbody>
</table>
@endsection
```

ERROR LOG from chrome console

[Vue warn]: Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements:

```
<tr v-for="list in UsersData">
    <th>{{ list.idx }}</th>
    <td>{{ list.id }}</td>
</tr>
```

vue.js:525 [Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node. 
(found in component )

How should I fix code?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your template has to have one root element. It's just one rule you cannot break. Since you're making a table, it would make sense to make `tbody` the root element.

```
var Users = {
    template: `
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="list in UsersData">
                <th>{{ list.idx }}</th>
                <td>{{ list.id }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    `,
    data: function () {
        return {
            UsersData //get data from query
        }
    }
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>IDX</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <users></users>
</table>
@endsection
```

Comment: I cannot wrap my template into <thead> or <tbody> because there is not the single <th v-for> loop in my cause but two, first one for special columns, another one for data columns. Wrapping everything into <template> also does not work.

Answer (score 37):

For the lazy: Vue interprets the root element having a `v-for` loop on it as producing multiple root level elements (a nono in modern JS frameworks).

Just wrap your template in a superfluous blank `<div>`.

Comment: Adding random <div>s in the middle of the table structure just to keep the framework happy?  That doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: I hate the answer. But it worked really well for me haha

Comment: Adding a <div> worked for me too but why do we need it in vue?

Comment: Why does v-for directive needs a single root element?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this, until I realized you can just add a section tag over everything in template and then this error goes away.
Example

```
//gives error 

<template> 
  <div classname="allFutures" v-for="(items, index) in arr">
      <Future title="Shee" />
    </div>
</template> 

    // do this instead

<template>
  <section id="main" class="main-alt">
    <div classname="allFutures" v-for="(items, index) in arr">
      <Future title="Shee" />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```